# Can i use Philosophical arguments to believe in Allah?

Tags: allah

There are many philosophical about the existence of Allah. Could i use these to strengthen my faith?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but be careful.

The Qur'an encourages us to ponder, reflect, and avoid blind faith. Muslims have been using philosophical proofs to strengthen their faith (and present their case) for centuries. See, for example, the [Burhan al-Siddiqeen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_the_Truthful) (Proof of the Truthful).

But! Be careful, at least for the following reasons:

- Some philosophical arguments or "proofs" might look correct, but actually have major weaknesses that can be very hard to detect. Or, they might be dealing with some different entity other than Allah, falsely linking ideas to Him that contradict how He has described Himself in the Qur'an. It would be bad to try and strengthen your faith using philosophical arguments that convey the wrong messages.
- Most specialists of modern, western philosophy tend towards atheism (for example, [source](https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/logical-take/201402/why-62-philosophers-are-atheists-part-i)). There is a real risk that reading too much from western philosophers will present doubts and confusion that end up weakening your faith. Exposing yourself to atheistic viewpoints without having an expert Muslim philosopher to answer the questions that come up can have a very damaging effect.